# SSD to usb: with case vs no case

Tags: usb, ssd

I got a SSD and I want to use it as a USB. There are two type: with case or without case. Which is better?

Example:

With case:

[image][image]

Without case:

[image][image]

Comment: What is the SSD you plan to use with these? Some M.2 SSDs have heatsinks on them and won't fit in a case. The answer depends if you care about compatibility with all SSDs or just a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it doesnt matter, choose the one you think looks best

Comment: If I use the SSD in a case, for a long time, will it overheat?

Comment: If you add a thermal pad, defenitly not, but the chances are always low in the way that most users use an ssd